# jQuery inArray matching wrong value using -1

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have an array with the value -1, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.
Im using this code the see if the value of a checkbox is in the array:

```
jQuery("#checkbox-container").find("input[type=\'checkbox\']").each(function() {
    var state = jQuery.inArray(this.value, targetarray)!=-1;
         
    jQuery(this).prop("checked", state);
});
```

It works with all numbers except -1. It will select the checkbox with value 1 instead of -1. Why does it do that?

Comment: Are you saying that, if `targetarray` is `[-1]`, that running this script will check a box with `value="1"` but not check a box with `value="-1"`?

Comment: And just for my curiousity, is there a reason you spell out `jQuery` instead of using the usual and more typing-efficient `$`?

Answer (score 1):

I used parseInt() to convert string into int.
If targetarray is given as array of int, but this.value is a string.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var targetarray = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#checkbox-container").find("input[type=\'checkbox\']").each(function() {
        var state = jQuery.inArray(parseInt(this.value), targetarray)!=-1;
        
        jQuery(this).prop("checked", state);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" value="-1">-1</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="0">0</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">1</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="2">2</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="3">3</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="4">4</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="5">5</input>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are right, this.value is of type 'string'